# Error in migrating Laravel after make:auth

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, laravel-5.4

I am trying to learn `Laravel 5.4`. After I publish the command `php artisan make:auth` and publish the command `php artisan migrate` the following errors get displayed and some database tables do not get greated:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key
>   was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `users`
>   add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))  [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key
>   was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Regarding the fact that I need to use some columns as a container of characters having `Persian Script Font` (some other columns contain English, Spanish ... characters), I created the `MySQL` database with `utf8_general_ci` and I suppose that the errors are initiated because of the database's encoding. Would you please tell me what `character encoding` I shall use to build the database with to be able to leverage Laravel's Auth capabilities? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Do not use images for text content.

Comment: @Parantap Parashar : Thank you sir for telling me about my mistake. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see the definition of `email`.

Meanwhile, I will guess that it includes something like

```
email VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
INDEX(email)
```

Do one of these (each has its drawbacks):

- 255 -> 191 (but make sure you don't currently have longer addresses)
- utf8mb4 -> utf8 (thereby disallowing Emoji and some Chinese characters)
- INDEX(email(20))  (If it is `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY`, do *not* pick this option)
- It is possible to reconfigure (if after 5.6.3) the server and table to allow bigger indexes; this is not the 'default' until 5.7.7.

Comment: Dearest sir, you helped me a lot and saved my entire life with the ever changing Laravel, and all its pros and cons. I looked carefully into `config/database.php` and saw what you had mentioned about the **utf8mb4**. Therefore I removed the `mb4` from `charset` and `collation` in `mysql` configuration and voila... it is working just fine now.  Thank you again for not only having complete information but also sharing it and helping us.

Comment: @Tower - You're welcome.  I enjoy answering MySQL questions, as is obvious from my 'reputation'.  I know nothing about Laravel, other than seeing that it obfuscates things with MySQL.  I added your tip to my list of tips:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll

Comment: @Rick.James: Thank you again especially for putting you web address in comments. As from the list jest right side of the page I think I can find lots of ideas there too. Wish you luck.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 5.4 has a [documented](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17508) issue on this error.

For others who run into this problem this is also a good fix:

1. open your `app\Provider\AppServiceProvider.php`
2. change it to:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Providers;

   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
   use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

   class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
   {
   /**
   * Bootstrap any application services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
   public function boot()
   {
   Schema::defaultStringLength(191); //
   }

   /**
   * Register any application services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
   public function register()
   {
   //
   }
   }
   ```
3. run migration again